# Only one dropdown open at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am a noob but I'm trying to learn js. Been toying around with this menu but I have been having trouble with an issue: using my code, how do I implement the behaviour of only having one dropdown open at a time, on mobile?

```
$(".menu > ul > li").click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
        $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
    }
});
```

This is a demo of my code: http://jsbin.com/sesuda/edit?html,output

The way this template works is it keeps all the dropdowns open.

What I have tried: using not(this) to only open the clicked dropdown item.
Also, using next(element) to only make the very next sibling (the dropdown content next to the dropdown link) visible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Disclaimer: sorry for the broken English, it's not my native language and I haven't slept for 24h.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fade out all elements, and then fade in clicked one

```
$(".menu > ul > li").click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
        $(".menu > ul > li > ul").fadeOut(150);
        $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. This works! However, minor issue, if I click on the same dropdown item again, it doesn't close it. I think your solution answers my original question, and you are awesome, but it introduces a slight issue.

Comment: `if ($(this).chldren("ul").is(':visible')) {
    $(this).children("ul").fadeOut(150);

} else {
    $(this).children("ul").fadeIn(150);
}`

Comment: I replaced the fadeToggle with your code but I must be doing something wrong, the dropdowns are not working at all: [jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/sesuda/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: sry, typo :) chldren -> children

Comment: Ha, no worries. [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sesuda/10/edit?html,css,js,output) – check it out, still not working...

Comment: You rock. This solves my problem. Now to actually deconstruct it and learn how it works. Thank you so much, Martin!

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly for me (Firefox 47). But I noticed you have a `.click` listener as well as a `.hover` listener. These might be interfering with eachother.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I will fix that later on. The issue I am trying to learn is how I can only display the contents of one dropdown at a time. On mobile: I click one dropdown, the other closes.